# How to insert post 6 times after user register like ask.fm

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-insert-post

I have a question and answer site like ask.fm. On ask.fm when you register a new account you found that you have 6 questions (posts).

I need to make the same. Whenever a user registers I need to add 6 different posts for this user.

I failed to call wp_insert_post more than one time.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Milo i try to insert wp_insert_post 6 times but sure this is not professional.